# How do I find the address of last non-blank cell in a row (while skipping columns)

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Basically, I need to do what the title says on my spreadsheet here. So for row 3, I need to find the **address** of the last non-blank cell in that row, while skipping the grayed out columns (with the header "Total").

[image]

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is in columns A:J (i.e., 1 to 10), and columns to be ignored are C and F (3 and 6), then for row 2 you would use

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(A2),SUMPRODUCT(MAX((A2:J2<>"")*(COLUMN(A2:J2))*(1-(COLUMN(A2:J2)=3))*(1-(COLUMN(A2:J2)=6)))))
```

Explanation:

1. `ADDRESS` builds the address, taking the row number (known here) and the column number (what you mean to get).
2. `SUMPRODUCT(MAX((A2:J2<>"")*(COLUMN(A2:J2)) ... ))` picks the maximum column number for non-blank cells.
3. `... *(1-(COLUMN(A2:J2)=3))*(1-(COLUMN(A2:J2)=6))` makes the formula ignore specific columns (3 and 6 here). You should add other similar factors if needed.

Copy the formula downwards.
Note that you might need to use some absolute references.

This also works

```
=ADDRESS(row(A2),INDEX(MAX((A2:J2<>"")*(COLUMN(A2:J2))*(1-(COLUMN(A2:J2)=3))*(1-(COLUMN(A2:J2)=6))),0))
```

Adapted from related answers

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30874261/simple-enquiry-with-complex-answer-how-do-i-select-rowa6-rowlast-non-blank-f/30875675#30875675

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19915043/2707864

Answer (score 0):

**1.** this can be solved with a middle step (side calculation):

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({O60; N60; J60}, "select *"),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not NULL"))
```

- selected columns **`{O60; N60; J60}`** needs to be in reverse alphabet order

### _______________________________________________________________

**2.** then you can get absolute reference with this formula:

```
=CELL("ADDRESS", INDEX(J60:60, MATCH(J60, J60:60, 0), 1))
```

### _______________________________________________________________

**3.** and if you want to drop absolute reference, you need to wrap it into **`REGEXREPLACE()`**:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(CELL("ADDRESS", INDEX(J60:60, MATCH(J60, J60:60, 0), 1)), "\$", "")
```

### _______________________________________________________________

[image: 6]