# How to make a formula so it repeats istself indefinetly

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a formula that does exactly what I need except for that, for now, I need to manually expand the range for which it applies.
What do I need to add so I only have this in one cell and it automatically applies for an infinite amount of rows?

```
=AND(D3:D=TRUE;E3:E>0;F3:F>0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA((D3:D=TRUE)*(E3:E>0)*(F3:F>0)=1)
```

Even shorter:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA((D3:D)*(E3:E>0)*(F3:F>0)=1)
```

If you need to combine an arbitrary number of `AND` / `OR` operations, simply add `(1-...)` and parentheses as needed.
See [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/125379/53294).

Comment: Tried the short one first, it worked like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(D3:D); IF((D3:D=TRUE) * (E3:E>0) * (F3:F>0); TRUE); ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This formula didn't work (error analyzing the formula)

Comment: answer updated (I forgot you are different locale...)

Comment: This works as well now, thanks for your time and effort